# How to get var in global object after function complete

Tags: angularjs, function, wait, var

Have a function that's convert *.csv file to JSON. 
In function I can print this JSON to console.log console.log(jsonner);
but I can't transfer it to Angular controller. $scope.names = jsonner;
I have 2 problems: how wait fuction, and how makes var jsonner global.

```
function csvJSON(csv){

  var lines=csv.split("\n");
  var result = [];
  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }

      result.push(obj);

  }

  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}

function processFiles(files) {
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
    // Когда это событие активируется, данные готовы.
    // Вставляем их в страницу в элемент <div>
    var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput");   
    output.textContent = e.target.result;
    content = output.textContent;
    jsonner = csvJSON(content);
    console.log(jsonner);
};
    reader.readAsText(file);

}




var SearchApp = angular.module('SearchApp',[]);
 SearchApp.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // Here the array would be your response.text:
    $scope.names = jsonner;

}]);
```

Comment: Object.assign(global,  jsonner); this will make aglobal jsonner and use it like global.jsonner in ur controller

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonner is not defined

Comment: where I must put it?

Comment: in ur function assign rsult like this global.jsonner = jsonner; and use in angular controller global.jsonner

Comment: ingnore 1st comment

Comment: I must put it in controller?   
Object.assign(global, jsonner);

Comment: put   global.jsonner = jsonner in ur function and access this result in controller like  global.jsonner

Comment: share ur code and i will modify and add for u

Comment: IDE says that global variable is not defined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o0831rbu/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o0831rbu/#&togetherjs=isnTHpHuih

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qa9yog80/ - makes new version but now error angular.js:13708Error: [$compile:ctreq]

Comment: @Umakant Mane do you see my code on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `$scope.names` is pointing to the original `jsonner` in memory.  You're creating a new object with `jsonner = csvJSON(content);` because it returns the `result` array.  You would have to modify the original array to get it to update the way you want.

Here is a demo of the working logic to get you started:  [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IAXMSbkVgX2zf6sFWaSz?p=preview)

Unfortunately `file` inputs don't work with `ng-change`, however there's a couple workarounds.  You can do this:

`<input id="fileInput" type="file" ng-model="files" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().processFiles(this)">`

or you can wire up the event using `element.on('change', processFiles)` within a custom directive. Here's what I did:

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl2">
  <input id="fileInput" type="file" ng-model="files" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().processFiles(this)">
  <div>{{ output }}</div>

  <div ng-repeat="todo in names track by $index" class="repeat">
      <div class="comname">{{todo.Name}}</div>
      <div class="price">{{todo.Price}}</div>
      <div class="change">{{todo.Change}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and the logic:

```
var SearchApp = angular.module('SearchApp', []);
SearchApp.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.processFiles = function (element) {
      var file = element.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        // Need to notify angular of this event using $apply
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          // Когда это событие активируется, данные готовы.
          // Вставляем их в страницу в элемент <div>
          var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput");
          $scope.output = e.target.result;
          jsonner = csvJSON(e.target.result);
          console.log(jsonner);
          $scope.names = jsonner;
        });
      };

      reader.readAsText(file);
    };


}]);
```

Comment: Where are these functions called?

Comment: <body ng-controller="ctrl2">
        <input id="fileInput" type="file" onchange="processFiles(this.files)">
        <div id="fileOutput"></div>
        
        <div ng-repeat="todo in names" class="repeat">
            <div class="comname">{{todo.Name}}</div>
            <div class="price">{{todo.Price}}</div>
            <div class="change">{{todo.Change}}</div>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>

Comment: Ok so these functions are being called in javascript outside of angularjs.  if you used ng-change then you could change the line to `$scope.names = csvJSON(content);` and in your controller put `$scope.processFiles = function(files){ ...} `

Comment: How I must write ng-change?

Comment: `<input id="fileInput" type="file" ng-change="processFiles(this.files)">`  You might need to wrap the logic inside `reader.onload = function (e) { }` with a `$scope.$apply()` if the `$scope.names` doesn't update.

Comment: please Could you do it on jsfiddle ?

Comment: ng-change="processFiles()"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qa9yog80/ - makes new version but now error angular.js:13708Error: [$compile:ctreq]

Comment: See my answer above

Comment: <div class="comname">{{todo.Name}}</div>
      <div class="price">{{todo.Price}}</div>
      <div class="change">{{todo.Change}}</div> not working (((

Comment: How about you provide me with some sample data so we can test the logic of your `csvJSON` function

Comment: See my plunker demo.  You had `return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON`.  I changed it to `return result;`.